# how can i make the text position responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

when I change the screen size the text how is in front of the slider moves,I uset the grid system in bootstrap 5.2 to position it.
I want the text how is in front of a carousel to stay in the same position when I change the screen size here is my code.
what can I do to fix it.

```css
#text-position{
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 999;
}
.carousel-caption h1{
    font-size: 100px;
}
.btn-lg{
    width: 200px !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.overlay { 
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:12;
    top:500px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 
 <main>
       <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner" >
           <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img src="images/hero1.png" class="d-block w-100" >
             
             
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item ">
             <img src="images/hero2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" >
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item ">
             <img src="images/hero3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" >
           </div>
         </div>
         <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="prev">
           <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
         </button>
         <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="next">
           <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="overlay">
        <div class="row">
         
      <div class="col-3 offset-1 "><h5>WE LOVE DESIGN</h5></div>
      
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 offset-1"><h1>CREATIVE MINDES</h1></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 offset-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg " data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">GET IN TOUTCH</button></div>
      </div>
      </div>
 </main>

   
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[this the web on a smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhP8K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the position where the text should be, so:

```
text-position{    
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
color: white;
z-index: 999;
top: 50%
right: 50%}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).